# Why am I getting this error: class CSE has no member named EnterRN and EnterName?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CSE
{
private:
    char Name;
    double Roll;

public:
    void getN(char N, double RN)
    {
        Name = N;
        Roll = RN;
    }
};
char EnterName()
{

    cout << "Enter the name of the student" << ;
}
char EnterRN()
{

    cout << "enter the rn" << ;
};
int main()
{
    CSE nnn;
    nnn.getN(N, RN);
    cout << "enter the name" << nnn.EnterName << endl;
    cout << "enter the roll" << nnn.EnterRN << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I correct here for the right implementation of my code? I just want to keep the names and roll number private and then public them afterwards. I also want to enter the name and roll number by the user and then display it.

Comment: Because you defined that function outside of your class maybe?!?

Comment: How can I fix that??

Comment: Define it inside of your class definition (move them before the ending brace (`};`) of your class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining (free) functions instead declaring and defining a method:

```
class CSE {
   ...
   public:
      char EnterRN();
};

char CSE::EnterRN() {
  ...
}
```

If you want to do it inline then the closing } of the class needs to be after those functions.